# Jest mock setTimeout - getting timeout error

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm writing a unit test which tests a function which waits a timeout before continuing, I've tried using

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.advanceTimersByTime(20000);
```

but I keep getting an error message:

`: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 20000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:`

**Module file**:

```
async function main()

{

   const promisesArray: Promise<void>[] = [];

   // lots of logic and async calls //

   for (const userRecord of records) {

      promisesArray.push(verifyUserRecord(userRecord.userId));

   }

   await Promise.all(promisesArray);
}


function waitTimeout(ms: number) {
     return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), ms));
}


 async function verifyUserRecord(userId) {
   
    await waitTimeout(CHECK_EXECUTION_STATUS_TIMEOUT);

    await <some other method call>
   /////////////// more logic /////////////
}
```

**Test File**

```
describe('main test', () => {
beforeAll(() => {
  // calls to jest spy on //
});
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  // various mocks //

});
afterEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks();
});
afterAll(() => {
  jest.useRealTimers();
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});
it('Should successfully run', async () => {
    const p = main();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(60000);
    jest.runAllTimers(); // <- explicitly tell jest to run all setTimeout, setInterval
    jest.runAllTicks(); // <- explicitly tell jest to run all Promise callback

    await p;

    // validations // 
  });
});
```

But when I call main method from the test file, I get the error above.
When debugging I see that it arrives to `waitTimeout` and then either waits or moves on to next `it` in the test module.
It does not mock the timeout, and continues the module file logic.

How can I properly test the file and mock the timeout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You use wrong API when mock timer

`jest.setTimeout(20000);` is used to set the maximum timeout that jest will wait for a test to finish. If a test take to long jest will throw errors

Back to your problem, since you use `jest.useFakeTimers();` you have to tell jest explicitly to exhaust all macro tasks (setTimeout) and micro tasks (Promise callback).

I modified your code a little so the expect works

```
const CHECK_EXECUTION_STATUS_TIMEOUT = 2000;
const records = [{ userId: 1 }, { userId: 2 }];

async function main() {
  const promisesArray: Promise<number>[] = [];

  for (const userRecord of records) {
    promisesArray.push(verifyUserRecord(userRecord.userId));
  }

  return await Promise.all(promisesArray);
}

function waitTimeout(ms: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), ms));
}

async function verifyUserRecord(userId: number) {
  await waitTimeout(CHECK_EXECUTION_STATUS_TIMEOUT);

  // await <some other method call>
  /////////////// more logic /////////////
  return userId;
}

describe("main", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers(); // <- use fake timer
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  it("should work", async () => {
    const p = main();
    jest.runAllTimers(); // <- explicitly tell jest to run all setTimeout, setInterval
    jest.runAllTicks(); // <- explicitly tell jest to run all Promise callback

    expect(await p).toEqual([1, 2]);
  });
});
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Tried your suggestion but I keep getting the same error

Comment: When debugging the test, I see that it bounces between the call to `waitTimeout`, it does not return to the test file to run the timers

Answer (score 3):

Another way to mock setTimeout:

```
jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout').mockImplementation((callback) => {
if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback();
}
return { hasRef: () => false } as NodeJS.Timeout;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `runOnlyPendingTimers`, this flushes all pending timers.

Usage

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

// call your function here

jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
```

Comment: Does not work, it waits the entire length of the timeout.

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev, why dont you mock Promise?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev, when writing a test for `main()`, mock  `waitTimeout()`. When writing a test for `waitTimeout` onlu then use fake timers

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution of [Linden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8820559/linden-x-quan) but i had to take a little care, i put the 'jest.spyOn' before the require of "my under test module"

something like this:

```
jest.spy(global, 'setTimeout').mockImplementation.....
// jest.spy before require
const mut = require('my_module_under_test');
```

In my case some submodule (used by my module under test), had a self call function that was using a 'setTimeout' to self recall it

something like this:

```
.....
function loop() {
  // do something
  setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}
loop();
.....
```